# Is it valid to use role = "listbox" to input element?

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

I am creating a custom control for multiselect such that I am using input element wrapped with a container to type the value and `ul` and `li` elements to show suggestions where I used role as listbox. In order to flexible with assistive standards, I am using the role of input element as listbox. The problem is that chrome accessibility lighthouse tool test cases getting failed. I went through some of the blogs and documentations about the role but I could not find any related things. So my question is am I allowed to change the role as textbox for this or to ignore the failed case thrown?

[image]

I gone through the below resources

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/textbox_role

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html

Suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you used role="option" on the <li> tags?

Comment: Yes. I used option as role in li tags